# Android: A service to listen Keyboard open/close on any context

Tags: java, android, keyboard, listener

I want a Global listener for Keyboard open/close events. (Not restricted to my app).

I did little research to realize there is no official way from Android to listen to Keyboard open/close events. Even though I did find a hack that listens to change in the size of current activity `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` to know when keyboard is open/close.

I want to know if I could implement (even a hack will do) using which I can implement a service that listens to Keyboard open/close irrespective of which app requests for the input method.

Any help is appreciated. 
Feel free to suggest edits.

Comment: "I can implement a service that listens to Keyboard open/close irrespective of which app requests for the input method" -- I hope not (other than by writing the input method itself), for security and privacy reasons. "Even though I did find a hack that listens to change in the size of current activity to know when keyboard is open/close" -- that is unlikely to be reliable, even on today's devices, as the activity does not always resize (e.g., phone in landscape). Android N multiwindow means that the activity will change size for other reasons.

Comment: @CommonsWare Well I did think of the Input method, but is it possible that I implement my own input method just to listen to keyboard open/close, and later allow the default keyboard to pop up? Sounds weird to me. Would be great to know how, if that's possible.

Comment: "...and later allow the default keyboard to pop up?" -- I doubt it.

Comment: @CommonsWare Calling the default keyboard explicitly is not possible unless I know! And in that scenario, if user is using a custom keyboard, that must be considered as well. Eager to know your ideas on this.